# jquery drag and drop animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have some UI functionality for drag and drop, but when an element is dropped, the animation makes it flit about all over the place for a split second before it appears in the newly dropped location.

Can anyone advise how to tackle this, so that the draggable element moves more cleanly into place on success?

Here is a snippet from the ajax call on successful drop:

```
...
success : function() {
      $(ui.draggable)
        .parent()
        .droppable("enable")
        .end()
        .appendTo(droppable)
        .parent()
        .droppable("disable");
    },
...
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure that code is not correct for setting draggable/droppables. check http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Comment: what about hide() before and then show() after the elem is in place!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested but something like this

```
success : function() {
      $(ui.draggable)
        .parent().hide().droppable("option", "disabled", false)
        .end()
        .appendTo(droppable).show()
        .droppable("option", "disabled", true);
    },
```

anyway you can also unbind the animation while the element is moving! but i don't know the rest of the code!